# How did Deb miss the freezer?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the first season of the television series Dexter, his sister Deb

> is dating a man who turns out to be the Ice Truck Killer. He has a gigantic industrial freezer inside his apartment where he kills his victims, with the door in plain view in the kitchen, right at the front of the apartment. The door is unmistakably a freezer door, and even has a window. In episode 11, Deb shows up at the killer's house and he invites her inside. We can see through the front door that the freezer door is clearly visible.

How could she possibly have missed such an obvious clue?

Comment: Because love makes you blind? ;-)

Comment: Deb conveniently misses a lot of things.

Comment: I want to answer with "she is an awful detective" but I fear it will be downvoted.

Comment: @Dpeif She's very insightful throughout the first season and regularly makes perfect deductions about her suspects. She even proposes this exact scenario later in this episode or the next. Also, it should have made her suspicious even if she *wasn't* a detective. It couldn't be any more conspicuous unless there was blood smeared across the door.

Answer (score 6):

It's because she was an innocent cop whose job was to follow the clues solve crime its only after the ice truck killer incident that she became the super cop debra that we know off, 
**ALSO** if you observe more closely into that episode the apartment door(which is partially visible when it is about to be closed) sort of resembles the freezer door and it might be a reason why she might have neglected it, BUT mainly i believe it is because she was innocent until the ice truck killer incident it's only after that the super cop instincts kicked in

Comment: As the question states, "In episode 11, Deb shows up at the killer's house and he invites her inside."

Comment: @war_Hero Completely wrong. She shows up unannounced at his house. They chat in the front doorway, and you can *see the freezer in the background*. Then he *invites her inside and she comes inside*. His apartment is arranged such that the freezer door is directly in front of you when you enter.

Comment: you are right i watched he episode yesterday check out the updated answer